# May i call presenter from model layer?

Tags: java, android-mvp

My Model class requests data from web api and if it finishes then i want to inform my Presenter about that, because i want to make my Presenter to hide `ProgressBar` at that moment.

Question:

How to do it correctly in order to MVP,

may i call presenter method from model layer?

Kind of that:

```
public class EventsRepository {
    ...
    if (requestCompleted()) {
        presenter.requestCompleted();
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Should model request data from web api, or should that be presenter's job?

Comment: Your leading question suggests its own answer. Actually, I've already found out, that repository's job is to get and store data and therefore actions i asked here about, originally are fall outside of scope  Presenter's responsibility. Thanks a lot!